# Regex to return last 3 characters of matching pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I am using grep to search through text files containing 88 character long MRZs (machine readable zones). Within the text file they are preceeded by a semicolon.
I only want to get the substring of characters 3-5 from the string.

This is my pattern:

```
egrep --include *.txt -or . -e ";[A-Z][A-Z0-9<][A-Z<]{3}"
```

This is a textfile:

```
text is here;P<RUSIVAN<<DEL<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<F64D123456RUS7404124F131009734P41234<<<<<<<8  ;2019-02-08
```

This is my output:

```
;P<RUS
```

This is my desired output:

```
RUS
```

The semicolon introduces the MRZ. It starts with a uppercase letter, followed by either an uppercase letter, a digit or a filler character `<`. Then follows the 3 digit country code that can contain uppercase letters or filler characters `<`.

This pattern works fine, but what I only want returned is the last  3 digits I am quantifying. Is there a way to get only the last 3 characters of a matching pattern?
In the sample text file the desired output would be `RUS`.
Thank you!

Comment: It would be very helpful to add some example strings.

Comment: @pjanssen sorry, was just editing the question

Comment: So first `<` is optional?

Comment: Can use also use GNU grep? `grep -roP --include=*.txt ";[A-Z][A-Z0-9<]\K[A-Z<]{3}"`

Comment: @revo yes, the first < can also be a digit or an uppercase letter.

Comment: `followed by either an uppercase letter, a digit or a filler character <` if it is `or` why do you have two of the conditions at the same time `P<`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you! I have tried to use the `\K` operator with egrep but it didnt work. With grep is works! Feel free to post as answer.

Comment: Using `egrep` you should enable `-P` as `-P -e ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use GNU Grep, you can make use of `\K` which will no longer include any of the previous matched characters in the match and then match your character class 3 times:

```
grep -roP --include=*.txt ";[A-Z][A-Z0-9<]\K[A-Z<]{3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -F';' '{print substr($2,3,3)}' file
RUS

$ sed -E 's/[^;]*;..(.{3}).*/\1/' file
RUS
```

If not then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

The UNIX command to **find** files is named `find`, btw, not `grep`. I know the GNU guys added a bunch of options for finding files to grep but just don't use them as they make your grep command unnecessarily complicated (and inconsistent with the other UNIX text processing tools) as it then needs arguments to `find` files as well as to `g/re/p` within the files. So your command line if you're using grep should be:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep 'stuff' {} +
```

not:

```
egrep --include *.txt -or . -e 'stuff'
```

and do the same for any other tool:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep 'stuff' {} +
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed  'stuff' {} +
find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk  'stuff' {} +
```

Comment: This doesn't take into consideration that a few of conditions are optional.

Comment: @revo I don't know exactly what that means but if there's input that this answer doesn't work for then it should be added to the question to create the necessary [mcve].